# How to save history data to different database in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using [django-tenants](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/) for creating multitenant app and have successfully done it. But now I want to save history data of tenants to a different database. How to accomplish this. Please help

Comment: Please add more info on what you tried so far and show us the code. Generally speaking: define a second DB in your settings.py and in your API view use the second one. There are some keywords in the django ORM you can use. google and enrich your question a little bit and we might be able to help you

Comment: Plus can you clarify what exactly you mean by "_history data of tenants_"? is it the historical data of some table of a tenant? Also this might not be very feasible if you consider you would need relations across the different databases.